# How to find the optimal sum

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Imagine this set of values:

```
      A B C
LINE1 2 1 1
LINE2 1 4 1
LINE3 3 1 3
LINE4 6 5 4
```

I can choose one value per line from 1 to 3. If I choose a value from a specific column, I need to sum the value from line 4.

Example:

```
2 (LINE1, COLUMN A)
1 (LINE2, COLUMN A)
3 (LINE3, COLUMN C)
```

So, as I chose values from COLUMN A, I need to sum both of them with the value of LINE 4. Final result:

```
      A B C
LINE1 2 - -
LINE2 1 - -
LINE3 - - 3
LINE4 6 - 4 

2 + 1 + 6 = 9
3 + 4 = 7
TOTAL: 16
```

The fact is: I need to retrieve the smaller possible total from the combination. I chose the numbers in the example randomly, but my algorithm need to choose numbers that give me the smaller total.

I think the optimal solution is to pick all numbers from COLUMN C (TOTAL: 9), but will be situations that I need to pick numbers from different columns.

I think it is a optimization problem and I thought to use simplex but I don't know how to start the development.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can solve this with the simplex algorithm as this is not a LP problem. For how many columns do you want to solve this?

Comment: I can't tell. The number of lines and columns are completely variable. I know that calculate all combinations to small sets is a easy approach but I'm afraid that the sets will continually grow. So I'm looking for a known algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with using GLPK in GNU MathProg modeling language. Note: This is literally the first thing I ever wrote in MathProg, so feedback is very welcome.

Specifically I'm not sure if the way I linked x[] and s[] is efficient (I'm more used to SAT CNF encodings than to ILP).

Save the code as `test.mod` and execute with `glpsol --math test.mod`.

```
set A, dimen 3;
set B, dimen 2;

set I := setof{(i,j,v) in A} i;
set J := setof{(i,j,v) in A} j;

var x{I, J}, binary;
var s{J}, binary;

s.t. lines {i in I}:
  sum{j in J} x[i, j] = 1;

s.t. rows {j in J, i in I}:
  x[i, j] <= s[j];

minimize obj:
  (sum{(i,j,v) in A} x[i, j]*v) + (sum{(j,v) in B} s[j]*v);

solve;

printf "Result:\n";
printf {(i,j,v) in A : x[i, j] == 1} " %3d %3d %5d\n", i, j, v;
printf {(j,v) in B : s[j] == 1} " --- %3d %5d\n", j, v;
printf " --- --- %5d\n", (sum{(i,j,v) in A} x[i, j]*v) + (sum{(j,v) in B} s[j]*v);
printf "\n";

data;

set A :=
# Line 1
  1 1 2
  1 2 1
  1 3 1
# Line 2
  2 1 1
  2 2 4
  2 3 1
# Line 3
  3 1 3
  3 2 1
  3 3 3;

set B :=
# Line 4
  1 6
  2 5
  3 4;

end;
```

Thanks to Robert for suggesting GLPK and providing an outline for the solution in his answer.

Comment: Hi Clifford! Thank you so much for your code. It's working perfectly. However it is possibly to show me the min Z equation? I understood the sets and the constraints but not the minimize objective.

Comment: @faelcorreia: I've now added printing of the values and the final sum to the  code. Is this what you where asking for? The minimize objective just tries to minimize the sum of all selected elements. (`x[i,j]*v` returns `v` if `x[i,j]` is `1` and `0` if `x[i,j]` is `0`.)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. In fact I was trying to express the problem in math expression. So using your code I've got this and now I fully understand.

Minimize p = 2aa + 1ab + 1ac + 1ba + 4 bb + 1bc + 3ca + 1cb + 3cc + 6d + 5e + 4f // subject to aa+ab+ac = 1 / ba+bb+bc = 1 / ca+cb+cc = 1 / aa - d <= 0 / ba - d <= 0 / ca - d <= 0 / ab - e <= 0 / bb - e <= 0 / cb - e <= 0 / ac - f <= 0 / bc - f <= 0 / cc - f <= 0

Thank you very much. I will try to use your code in Java now. :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an example of a so-called 0-1 assignment problem; a web search for that term should turn up a lot of hits. It is a special case of a linear programming problem. There are several software packages that could be useful. I have used GLPK for various problems and found it to be very useful. Don't bother trying to write your software for this problem; it is extremely difficult, and you needn't bother.

To describe this as a 0-1 assignment problem, let Ajk be the values in the table you showed, and introduce binary variables x11, x12, x13; x21, x22, x23; x31, x32, x33; etc (i.e. xjk for the k'th element of the j'th row) and minimize the sum of xjk times Ajk, subject to the constraint that the row sum xj1 + xj2 + xj3 = 1 for each row j. That is, xjk selects (if xjk = 1) or omits (if xjk = 0) the corresponding value Ajk, and exactly one value is selected from each row.

GLPK for instance allows you to describe such problems in terms very similar to that.

If I've misunderstood the problem, you'll have to adjust what I said about the constraints and so on. Good luck & have fun. Constrained optimization problems are always interesting.

Comment: Thank you, Robert! I will study this and I return to tell if it works now. =)

Comment: You're right, it can be solved as an integer linear programming problem. With (rows) x (columns) variables :-( Have never tried how quick a solver can handle that kind of problem.

Comment: Robert, thank you again. I will choose the answer of Clifford due the code (GLPK is completely new for me) but, as he said, the answer was possibly due to your help.

Answer (score 1):

In this examples, there are seven sets of columns that you could choose from: A, B, C, A and B, A and C, B and C, A, B and C. If that set of columns is fixed you pick the smallest value in each line that belongs to one of those columns. The smallest total is the winner.

```
A: 2 + 1 + 3 + 6 = 12.
B: 1 + 4 + 1 + 5 = 11
C: 1 + 1 + 3 + 4 = 9

AB: 1 + 1 + 1 + 6 + 5 = 14
AC: 1 + 1 + 3 + 6 + 4 = 15
BC: 1 + 1 + 1 + 5 + 4 = 12

ABC: 1 + 1 + 1 + 6 + 5 + 4 = 18.
```

Of course for k columns there are almost 2^k possibilities to choose the column; with every choice of columns the rest of the calculation is trivial.

Comment: So calculate all the possibilities is the only way? The number of columns can grow much more than three.

Comment: I wouldn't say the _only_ way. First, if you have say three columns and hundred lines, this algorithm is excellent. If you have hundred columns and three lines, then quite obviously most sets of columns need not be checked. In the general case (100 lines, 100 columns), the problem seems tricky to solve quickly.

Comment: Always good to try and simplify the problem first. For example, it would be obvious that you aren't going to use column A and B instead of just column A: Using column B costs 5 units, but saves at most three units in line 1 and 3. Actually, you'd never use column A because using column C is always better, so you can eliminate a whole column. You might find many conditions like "if the solution includes column X then it doesn't include column Y, or both Y and Z", possibly with huge simplifications.

Comment: All in all, I suppose you will often be able to solve with say 20 columns and any number of lines, if you manage to eliminate many of the 2^20 combinations of columns, and the rest should be calculated very quickly.