# How to penalize values to use in Simplex

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Well, suppose there are three values:

```
A | B | C
3 | 2 | 10
```

The three values are prices of a item X in three different suppliers. However, there are three different delivery times:

```
    | A | B | C
   $| 3 | 2 | 10
TIME| 2 | 4 | 3
```

How to penalize the values using the delivery time? I want to do this because I'm using Simplex from LpSolve (JAVA) to find the smallest value (Topic: [How to find the optimal sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487133/how-to-find-the-optimal-sum)).

My first thought: Value * (Delivery time / Delivery time average)

Example above:

```
Delivery time average: 9/3 = 3
First value penalized: 3 * (2/3) = 2

A | B    | C
2 | 2.66 | 10
```

This is fair?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fair if that is what you want. A generalisation of that approach would be to attach a cost for waiting, and minimise the total cost. The waiting time cost can either be real (e.g. a delivery delay is costing me $x per day to keep a workforce idle) or nominal (I am willing to pay $y to get something delivered a day earlier); both of these have the same form in practice - they add terms into the objective function.